# How do I restore focus to previously focused control of the TabPage when switching between tabs

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, tabcontrol

I have a TabControl and I'm adding Tabpages to it programmatically.
Each TabPage loads a UserControl in it, and each user control contains a few controls. For example:

```
TabPage1
   UserControl1
      TextBox1, TextBox2, TextBox3
TabPage2
   UserControl2
      TextBox4, TextBox5, TextBox6
```

Now I want that whenever the user changes the tab, the previously-focused control of that tab get focus again when the tab is selected again.

Example:

1. Let's say the focus is on TabPage1 → UserControl1 → TextBox2
2. Then I click on TagPage 2 → UserControl2 → TextBox4
3. Then I again click on TabPage1 and I want TextBox2 get the focus.

What shall I do?

Comment: This question demonstrates a common misconception among beginner programmers. They think that they should be able to write code without knowing what that code has to do and, if they can't, then they should down tools and wait for someone else to write the code for them. That's wrong. You should not be trying to write code without having a clear idea of what the code has to do first. That means not just the end result but the steps to get there. Code is just an implementation of logic and it takes no programming experience at all to determine what logic your code needs to implement.

Comment: Write an event handler for the tabcontrol's SelectedIndexChanged event and call, say, TabControl1.SelectNextControl(TabControl1, True, True, True, True).  Do note a grave usability problem with this feature, the user can no longer select the active tab with the keyboard anymore.

Comment: You should start by determining how you would accomplish the task manually - as I said, no programming experience necessary. You should break the steps down into the smallest pieces you can and formalise them into an algorithm. You can then test that algorithm with pen and paper - no programming experience necessary. You can then try to implement each step individually and, if you encounter an actual issue, you can describe the algorithm, the step and the issue to us. If you have no idea at all then you haven't really considered the problem.

Comment: Yes, there may be some parts that you need help implementing but that doesn't mean that you can't work out the logic for yourself. That's the problem. People don't want to work out logic and then write code to implement that logic. They just want to write code. That you can't write code of the top of your head doesn't mean that you can't solve the problem but, as is often the case, there's no indication that you've tried. If you need help with something specific then ask about that specifically, not the whole thing.

Comment: @John No its not like that john. I created the whole project alone which took me 2 years. My fault is that I took this old programming language. Now I am trying something new with the UI and UI are always headache. Backends are always easy. There are a lot things to see.  Like if the user will be able to interact properly or not. If user faces any glitches or errors, etc etc etc. I agree your approach but this language has some limitation and where my brain sometimes stops working I ask here if I get another approach to solve.

Comment: @HansPassant How do I do that? I mean I want to get a focus in usercontrol's control and I called a new tabpage on button click event and used the usercontrol's object there which closes there in `button_click` event.

Comment: It's exactly like that. That you have done work elsewhere is not relevant to this particular issue. You could work out the logic first but you aren't doing so. You don't have to do anything you don't want to but let's not pretend that that's not what's happening. The logic involved has absolutely nothing to do with any programming language or even programming. It's just logic. Thinking about logic isn't sexy like writing code is and it can be hard. That's why people don't want to do it sometimes. If you're determined to pretend you're doing otherwise, I can't help further.

Comment: [Not all questions benefit from including code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and IMO its one of those questions that doesn't require code, and it's in fact a nice question.

Comment: @bonny I edited the question to make it clearer and in a better format. Feel free to revert changes if you don't like the edit that I've done :)

Comment: Ye question you edited is good. An idea or answer or link will help me too. Btw nice to see you after a long time. @RezaAghaei

Comment: @bonny Thanks, Likewise! Now you have an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible solution:

Override [UpdateDefaultButton()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.updatedefaultbutton) in your Form; this method is called each time a Control becomes the `ActiveControl`.
Of course, if you have UserControls inside TabPages, the ActiveControl is the UserControl, but you need its child Control that is currently focused.

In the sample code, I'm using the [GetFocus()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getfocus) function to get the handle of the focused Control, then use [Control.FromHandle()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.fromhandle) to get the Control instance with that handle and, if it's not `null`, store this information in a Dictionary, along with the current TabPage.

When the TabControl's [Selected](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.selected) event is raised, check whether the Dictionary has stored the new current TabPage and, if a Control is associated with that TabPage, move the focus on it.
(I'm using `BeginInvoke()` because we're changing the ActiveControl in the `Selected` handler, which would in turn cause a call to `UpdateDefaultButton()`)

- Note that I'm not verifying here whether the Focused Control is child of a different container than the TabPage: if you have nested Containers in your TabPages, you need a recursive method that checks whether one of the ancestors is a TabPage.

```
Private tabPagesActiveControl As New Dictionary(Of Integer, Control)

Protected Overrides Sub UpdateDefaultButton()
    MyBase.UpdateDefaultButton()
    If ActiveControl Is Nothing Then Return

    If TypeOf ActiveControl.Parent Is TabPage Then
        Dim tp = DirectCast(ActiveControl.Parent, TabPage)
        Dim tabPageIdx = DirectCast(tp.Parent, TabControl).SelectedIndex
        Dim ctl = FromHandle(GetFocus())

        If ctl IsNot Nothing Then
            If tabPagesActiveControl.Count > 0 AndAlso tabPagesActiveControl.ContainsKey(tabPageIdx) Then
                tabPagesActiveControl(tabPageIdx) = ctl
            Else
                tabPagesActiveControl.Add(tabPageIdx, ctl)
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub TabControl1_Selected(sender As Object, e As TabControlEventArgs) Handles TabControl1.Selected
    Dim ctl As Control = Nothing
    If tabPagesActiveControl.TryGetValue(e.TabPageIndex, ctl) Then
        BeginInvoke(New Action(Sub() ctl.Focus()))
    End If
End Sub
```

Win32 Function declaration:

```
<DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)>
Friend Shared Function GetFocus() As IntPtr
End Function
```

---

**C# Version**:

```
private Dictionary<int, Control> tabPagesActiveControl = new Dictionary<int, Control>();

protected override void UpdateDefaultButton()
{
    base.UpdateDefaultButton();
    if (ActiveControl is null) return;

    if (ActiveControl.Parent is TabPage tp) {
        var tabPageIdx = (tp.Parent as TabControl).SelectedIndex;
        var ctl = FromHandle(GetFocus());
        if (ctl != null) {
            if (tabPagesActiveControl.Count > 0 && tabPagesActiveControl.ContainsKey(tabPageIdx)) {
                tabPagesActiveControl[tabPageIdx] = ctl;
            }
            else {
                tabPagesActiveControl.Add(tabPageIdx, ctl);
            }
        }
    }
}

private void tabControl1_Selected(object sender, TabControlEventArgs e)
{
    if (tabPagesActiveControl.TryGetValue(e.TabPageIndex, out Control ctl)) {
        BeginInvoke(new Action(() => ctl.Focus()));
    }
}
```

Win32 Function declaration:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
internal static extern IntPtr GetFocus();
```

This is how it works:
Note: `TabPage2` and `TabPage3` contain the instance of a UserControl with 2 TextBoxes and a ListBox. `TabPage1` contains a TextBox and a NumericUpDown.

[image: TabControl TabPage restore ActiveControl]

Comment: I don't know what wrong I did. Your answer is what I needed but I write code in VB.NET. I myself converted to vb.net (with help of internet and not online converters) but I guess there is some mistake. Please check the code if possible in the following link. [MyCode](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VbLJp6-FVMg1kqgxe25STeFiWaUkohu8/view?usp=sharing) . The link is just a jpg image of your converted code. Can you tell me whats wrong.??

Comment: As you said tabpage2 and tabpage 3 contain instance of usercontrol. I tried the same, made a usercontrol uc1 called in tabpage and open tabpage twice. and trying to switch. I get focus on 1st textbox only. Suppose I focused on 2nd textbox and come back after switching then 2nd textbox isnt selected

Comment: Oops, you tagged this question `vb.net` and I posted C# code. Sorry about that. I'm posting a vb.net version in a few minutes. What is your VB.Net version and what .Net version are you targeting?

Comment: Targeting to .NET Framework 4.8.
How to get `vb.net` version??? I searched internet, they say that if using vs2008 and above then its vb.net version 9. I am using vs 2017 so assuming that might be version 9

Comment: Also check my link I posted in above 1st comment.. :)

Comment: All right, the VB.Net version is in its place :) -- You don't call `UpdateDefaultButton()`, the Parent Form does, when the `ActiveControl` changes. -- Your VB.Net and Framework version are OK for this.

Comment: OMG thanks.. Its working now like magic. Thanks alot @Jimi

Comment: Ok I got 1 problem in this solution.
If I open 3 tabs, then it works fine but when I close a middle tab then focus in all other tabs stops working.

Comment: If you remove a TabPage, at run-time, after the Dictionary already contains the index Key that points to that TabPage, the Dictionary is out of synch. E.g., if you remove theTabPage at index `1`, the TabPage that was at index `2` is now at index `1`, so the Dictionary Key which has `1` as value, points to a different (wrong) Active Control for that page. You have to re-synchronize the Dictionary if a TabPage is removed. E.g., the Control reference at Key `1` is now the Control at Key `2` and so on. The last Key is removed in the end. The opposite if you insert a new TabPage

Comment: can you help me with this?? I understood what to do. Like when I close the tab I've to resync in the dictionary. But due to my lack of knowledge in the code, I am unable to achieve it.

Comment: Also you are saving tabindex in dictionary. Can I do it like save tab Name?? It'll be easier to achieve the desired result. A minor change I need to make is everytime tab opens, it gives a serial number after tab name like TabName1, TabName2. In such way I can track tab easily.